# HttpClient not retrieving json data in Angular 6

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient

I'm trying to use HttpClient from Angular 6 and I have been getting some issues.

My code looks like this:

**TS**

```
btc = this.http.get<any>(this.btcurl).subscribe(res => this.btc = res);

  eth = this.http.get<any>(this.ethurl).subscribe(res => this.eth = res);

  ltc = this.http.get<any>(this.ltcurl).subscribe(res => this.ltc = res);

  progressInfoData = [
    {
      title: 'Bitcoin (BTC) Price',
      value: this.btc,
      activeProgress: 70,
      description: 'Better than last week (70%)',
    },
    {
      title: 'Ethereum (ETH) Price',
      value: this.eth,
      activeProgress: 30,
      description: 'Better than last week (30%)',
    },
    {
      title: 'Litecoin (LTC) Price',
      value: this.ltc,
      activeProgress: 55,
      description: 'Better than last week (55%)',
    },
  ];
```

As you can see, I'm getting the info from an url and then I'm saving this info in an array. The problem is when I print this info I'm not getting the json object.

**HTML**:

```
<nb-card size="medium">
  <nb-card-body>
    <div class="progress-info" *ngFor="let item of progressInfoData | async">
      <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
      <div class="value">{{ item.value.EUR }}</div>
      <nb-progress-bar [value]="item.activeProgress"></nb-progress-bar>
      <div class="description">
        <bdi>{{ item.description }}</bdi>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

However, If I put in html code the var directly:

```
 <div class="value">{{ btc.EUR }}</div>
```

It prints the info correctly. Have you any idea why is this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you try to remove that <any> invocation and put some { } on the =>

Comment: When you are using async pipes you don't need to use subscribe. Async pipes will do the lifescycle of an observable for you (subscribing and destroying the subscription to avoid memory leaks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML snippet, `async` pipe has been used with `progressInfoData` but `progressInfoData` is not an observable. The observable in the array is just the `value` property. So `async` pipe should be used with `value` instead.

```
<nb-card size="medium">
  <nb-card-body>
    <div class="progress-info" *ngFor="let item of progressInfoData">
      <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
      <div class="value">{{ (item.value | async)?.EUR }}</div>
      <nb-progress-bar [value]="item.activeProgress"></nb-progress-bar>
      <div class="description">
        <bdi>{{ item.description }}</bdi>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

The change is here:

`<div class="progress-info" *ngFor="let item of progressInfoData">`

`<div class="value">{{ (item.value | async)?.EUR }}</div>`

Since you are using `async` pipe on the template, you do not need to subscribe to it in the component - like Patricio Vargas mentioned above. So, you can get rid of the subscriptions in the component.

Comment: P.D. Reusing this thread, How can I do this http.get calls continuously? I mean every 5 seconds for example, or even better when detects some change If It is possible. I have seen interval method but It is not working right for me.